# How to search for subarrays with a specific ids and generate a new array from their elements?

Tags: php, arrays, search, multidimensional-array, foreach

I've been trying to organize data into a multidimensional array from a foreach loop but the data is all over the place.

This is what I coded:

```
$productIDs = array(
    '0' => array(
        'product_id' => '10',
        'product_name' => 'Test',
        'product_file' => 'file10',
        'product_image' => 'https://i.imgur.com/dXb6.png',
    ),
    '1' => array(
        'product_id' => '20',
        'product_name' => 'Test1',
        'product_file' => 'file20',
        'product_image' => 'https://i.imgur.com/MuP8.png',
    ),
    '2' => array(
        'product_id' => '30',
        'product_name' => 'No product',
        'product_file' => 'file30',
        'product_image' => 'https://i.imgur.com/kWP3.png',
    )
);

$urlIDs  = array(10,20);

function getFiles($productIDs, $urlIDs)
{   
    foreach($productIDs as $ids)
    {
        foreach($urlIDs as $products)
        {   
            if(in_array($products, $ids)){
                $data1[] = $ids['product_id'];
                $data2[] = $ids['product_file'];
                $data3[] = $ids['product_image'];
            }
        }
    }
    return array($data1, $data2, $data3);
}
$getFiles = getFiles($productIDs, $urlIDs);
```

And the output for the following is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 20
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => file10
            [1] => file20
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => https://i.imgur.com/dXb6.png
            [1] => https://i.imgur.com/MuP8.png
        )

)
```

Although what I'm trying to accomplish is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [file] => file10
            [image] => https://i.imgur.com/dXb6.png
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 20
            [file] => file20
            [image] => https://i.imgur.com/MuP8.png
        )

)
```

I tried the following:

```
function getFiles($productIDs, $urlIDs)
{   
    foreach($productIDs as $ids)
    {
        foreach($urlIDs as $products)
        {   
            if(in_array($products, $ids)){
                $data['id'] = $ids['product_id'];
                $data['file'] = $ids['product_file'];
                $data['image'] = $ids['product_image'];
            }
        }
    }
    return array($data);
}
```

Which returns the following without looping through all id's, it should return both arrays since both id's are matching.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 20
            [file] => file20
            [image] => https://i.imgur.com/MuP8.png
        )

)
```

You could say the first batch of code without the specific key names isn't what I want, but I just wanted to show what I had tried. The last batch works (with key names), but doesn't loop through all of the `$urlIDs`, and for some reason that I can't understand, the code isn't even returning id = 10, it's returning id = 20, though it's second in the array. If someone could explain why this is happening I'd appreciate it.

In case it's useful: https://eval.in/764083

Comment: The reason that your last method is not storing the `id=10` subarray is because you are overwriting `$data` on each qualifying iteration.  In other words, `id=10` is being stored, then `id=20` is replacing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PHP code demo](https://eval.in/764110)

```
<?php
$productIDs = array(
    '0' => array(
        'product_id' => '10',
        'product_name' => 'Test',
        'product_file' => 'file10',
        'product_image' => 'https://i.imgur.com/dXb6.png',
    ),
    '1' => array(
        'product_id' => '20',
        'product_name' => 'Test1',
        'product_file' => 'file20',
        'product_image' => 'https://i.imgur.com/MuP8.png',
    ),
    '2' => array(
        'product_id' => '30',
        'product_name' => 'No product',
        'product_file' => 'file30',
        'product_image' => 'https://i.imgur.com/kWP3.png',
    )
);

$urlIDs  = array(10,20);

function getFiles($productIDs, $urlIDs)
{   
    $result=array();
    foreach($productIDs as $key => $productData)
    {
        if(!in_array($productData['product_id'],$urlIDs))
        {
            unset($productIDs[$key]);
        }
        else
        {
            $result[]=array("id"=>$productData['product_id'],"file"=>$productData['product_file'],"image"=>$productData['product_image']);
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
$getFiles = getFiles($productIDs, $urlIDs);
print_r($getFiles);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [file] => file10
            [image] => https://i.imgur.com/dXb6.png
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 20
            [file] => file20
            [image] => https://i.imgur.com/MuP8.png
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
function getFiles($productIDs, $urlIDs)
{   
$newDara = [];
    foreach($productIDs as $ids)
    {
        foreach($urlIDs as $products)
        {   
            if(in_array($products, $ids)){
                $data['id'] = $ids['product_id'];
                $data['file'] = $ids['product_file'];
                $data['image'] = $ids['product_image'];
                $newData[] = $data;
            }
        }
    }
    return array($newData);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Leveraging your tried out solution, change your tried solution to this.

```
function getFiles($productIDs, $urlIDs)
{

    foreach($productIDs as $ids)
    {
        foreach($urlIDs as $products)
        {
            if(in_array($products, $ids)){
                $data[] = [ "id" => $ids['product_id'],
                            "file" => $ids['product_file'],
                            "image" => $ids['product_image']];
            }
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this version**

```
    <?php
    /**
     * Created by PhpStorm.
     * User: lenovo
     * Date: 3/30/2017
     * Time: 5:53 AM
     */
    $productIDs = array(
        '0' => array(
            'product_id' => '10',
            'product_name' => 'Test',
            'product_file' => 'file10',
            'product_image' => 'https://i.imgur.com/dXb6.png',
        ),
        '1' => array(
            'product_id' => '20',
            'product_name' => 'Test1',
            'product_file' => 'file20',
            'product_image' => 'https://i.imgur.com/MuP8.png',
        ),
        '2' => array(
            'product_id' => '30',
            'product_name' => 'No product',
            'product_file' => 'file30',
            'product_image' => 'https://i.imgur.com/kWP3.png',
        )
    );

    $urlIDs  = array(10,20);

    $ouput = [];

    foreach($productIDs as $product){

        if(in_array($product['product_id'],$urlIDs)){
           $ouput[] = array("id"=>$product["product_id"], "file"=>$product["product_file"], "image"=>$product["product_image"]);
        }
    }

   echo "<pre>";
     print_r($ouput);
    echo "</pre>";
```

Check the [image: output here]

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are either doing too many loops, or looping through the `$productIDs` array (which I assume is much longer in your actual project).

This method will only iterate on your search array, this should provide a performance boost.  You will see this approach posted as the top comment @ http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4e974353dfc09b04901160fd7125bb029031c0b8))

```
$productIDs = array(
    '0' => array(
        'product_id' => '10',
        'product_name' => 'Test',
        'product_file' => 'file10',
        'product_image' => 'https://i.imgur.com/dXb6.png',
    ),
    '1' => array(
        'product_id' => '20',
        'product_name' => 'Test1',
        'product_file' => 'file20',
        'product_image' => 'https://i.imgur.com/MuP8.png',
    ),
    '2' => array(
        'product_id' => '30',
        'product_name' => 'No product',
        'product_file' => 'file30',
        'product_image' => 'https://i.imgur.com/kWP3.png',
    )
);
$urlIDs=array(10,20);
foreach($urlIDs as $prd_id){
    if(($i=array_search($prd_id,array_column($productIDs,'product_id')))!==false){
        $result[]=['id'=>$productIDs[$i]['product_id'],
                   'file'=>$productIDs[$i]['product_file'],
                   'image'=>$productIDs[$i]['product_image']
                  ];
    }else{
        echo "$prd_id not found";
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => '10',
    'file' => 'file10',
    'image' => 'https://i.imgur.com/dXb6.png',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => '20',
    'file' => 'file20',
    'image' => 'https://i.imgur.com/MuP8.png',
  ),
)
```